# changing option value text in woocommerce checkout

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

I need to change the `<option value>` on the woocommmerce checkout country list and I have no idea how to do it.
I am using a font that I think it has a bug, and it changes the `...` of `Select a country...` to the number 9, so instead of having `Select a country...` it shows `Select a country9` on the drop down list.
I can't find on the internet how to change the option value text.
Could someone help me?

```
<select name="billing_country" id="billing_country" class="country_to_state country_select fl-select" autocomplete="country"><option value="">Select a country…</option>
```

[image: here it's a screenshoot]

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with unicode character, writing `&#8230;` instead of `…`

*Reference: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm*